# dealing with external data sources when running destroy in terraform

Tags: terraform

For an external data source, I need to run a bash command when I run terraform destroy.

Is there a way to do an if to trigger this?

```
data "external" "token" {
  program = ["sh", "${path.module}/get_token.sh"]
query = {
    controller = "${packet_device.controller.network.0.address}"
  }
}
```

maybe using an if counter? but somehow making sure its run with destroy

```
  count = var.myInitExData ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that works, but you could try `null_resource` with a [Destroy-Time provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html#destroy-time-provisioners):

```
resource "null_resource" "token" {

  triggers = {
    token = data.external.token.result
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = "destroy"
    working_dir = path.module

    command = "destroy_time_script.sh"
    interpreter = ["sh"]
  }
}
```